# Skip a submodule during a Maven build

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, jenkins

We have a need to be able to skip a submodule in certain environments.

The module in question contains integration tests and takes half an hour to run.  So we want to include it when building on the CI server, but when developers build locally (and tests get run), we want to skip that module.

Is there a way to do this with a profile setting?  I've done some googling and looked at the other questions/answers here and haven't found a good solution.

I suppose one option is to remove that submodule from the parent `pom.xml` entirely, and just add another project on our CI server to just build that module.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why not Maven Way? It's a perfectly valid claim to me.

Comment: Hmm.  Now I can't find the places where people seemed to be arguing against this... so I've updated my original question to remove my claim that this doesn't seem to be "The Maven Way".

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Sure, this can be done using profiles.  You can do something like the following in your parent pom.xml.

```
  ...
   <modules>
      <module>module1</module>
      <module>module2</module>  
      ...
  </modules>
  ...
  <profiles>
     <profile>
       <id>ci</id>
          <modules>
            <module>module1</module>
            <module>module2</module>
            ...
            <module>module-integration-test</module>
          </modules> 
      </profile>
  </profiles>
 ...
```

In your CI, you would run maven with the `ci` profile, i.e. `mvn -P ci clean install`

Comment: Excellent answer!  I don't know why I had so much trouble finding this out of the Maven docs.  The one suggestion I would make is that because I prefer the integration tests to be run by default, I added `activeByDefault` to that profile, and then had to add another empty profile (e.g. `skip-integration-tests`) to be able to skip them.

Comment: is there any way to do this without duplicating all the shared stuff?

Comment: Beware, if you use the maven-release-plugin it would appear that it doesn't update the version number of submodules that are hidden behind a profile switch.  You could have sub-modules with different version numbers to the rest of your project...

Comment: Unfortunately, uing the profile you can't  exclude a module earlier mentioned in the main <modules> part of the pom.  The JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230 (and whole pom structure) could have been fully-implemented so much better with a bit more careful thought.

Comment: does this solution really work? At least I can not get it to work. Seems like I have the same issue like @EdRandall

Comment: this solution is not practical when you have multiple modules on a same profile. It's not the best practice to make every possibile combination of profiles in order to match every single possibility to compile or not certain modules.

Comment: this is NOT a correct answer and it does NOT work.

Answer (score 317):

Maven version 3.2.1 added this feature, you can use the `-pl` switch ([shortcut](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/cli.html) for `--projects` list) with `!` or `-` ([source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230#comment-14418377)) to exclude certain submodules.

```
mvn -pl '!submodule-to-exclude' install
mvn -pl -submodule-to-exclude install
```

Be careful in bash the character ! is a special character, so you either have to single quote it (like I did) or escape it with the backslash character.

The syntax to exclude multiple module is the same as the inclusion

```
mvn -pl '!submodule1,!submodule2' install
mvn -pl -submodule1,-submodule2 install
```

**EDIT** Windows does not seem to like the single quotes, but it is necessary in bash ; in Windows, use double quotes (thanks @awilkinson)

```
mvn -pl "!submodule1,!submodule2" install
```

Comment: Important: if you want to exclude a nested submodule you need to use the qualified version `mvn -pl !com.acme:nestedmodule1`

Comment: The -pl option need '[groupId]:' before artifactId , so we should use  mvn -pl '!:submodule-to-exclude' install

Comment: You can also use `mvn -pl '!path/to/submodule/directory'`, without using groupId and artifactId. My answer works if `submodule1` and `submodule2` are located in the current directory.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that if you use `-pl` in `mvn install`, you'll likely need to use it for `mvn deploy` as well

Comment: Following works on windows machine. `mvn -pl "!submodule1,!submodule2" clean install`

Comment: is there any option via profile?

Comment: Yeap double quotes is a must!
Windows, single quotes were treated as part of the name.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 41):

It's possible to decide which reactor projects to build by specifying the `-pl` command line argument:

```
$ mvn --help
[...]
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Build specified reactor projects
                                        instead of all projects
[...]
```

It accepts a comma separated list of parameters in one of the following forms:

- relative path of the folder containing the POM
- `[groupId]:artifactId`

Thus, given the following structure:

```
project-root [com.mycorp:parent]
  |
  + --- server [com.mycorp:server]
  |       |
  |       + --- orm [com.mycorp.server:orm]
  |
  + --- client [com.mycorp:client]
```

You can specify the following command line:

```
mvn -pl .,server,:client,com.mycorp.server:orm clean install
```

to build everything. Remove elements in the list to build only the modules you please.

---

EDIT: as [blackbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3071225/blackbuild) pointed out, as of Maven 3.2.1 you have [a new `-el` flag](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230) that excludes projects from the reactor, similarly to what  `-pl` does:

Comment: Thanks. This worked well for me. Also note that you can add the "-am" (AKA "--also-make") to also build projects that are required by the modules you have specified.

Comment: Great! I used `mvn install -pl .` in order to install parent pom only in local repo without building modules.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5230. You can now exclude projects from the reactor.

Comment: MNG-5230 link since codehaus.org closed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work transitively, ie, if I have top/mod1/mod2, and build from top, -pl '!mod2' raises an error.

Answer (score 9):

Given answers here for command line usage don't work currently on newer versions of maven (at least 3.8) You also need to add '**:**'

```
mvn -pl '!:mymodule' install
```

Comment: we have double hierarchy of reactors and this doesnt seem to work to exclude on of the middle level reaktor modules.

Answer (score 4):

The notion of multi-module projects is there to service the needs of codependent segments of a project.  Such a client depends on the services which in turn depends on say EJBs or data-access routines.  You *could* group your continuous integration (CI) tests in this manner.  I would rationalize that by saying that the CI tests need to be in lock-step with application logic changes.

Suppose your project is structured as:

```
project-root
  |
  + --- ci
  |
  + --- client
  |
  + --- server
```

The `project-root/pom.xml` defines modules

```
<modules>
  <module>ci</module>
  <module>client</module>
  <module>server</module>
</modules>
```

The `ci/pom.xml` defines profiles such as:

```
... 
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>CI</id>
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <skip>false</skip>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This will result in Maven skipping tests in this module except when the profile named `CI` is active.
Your CI server must be instructed to execute `mvn clean package -P CI`.  The Maven web site has an [in-depth explanation of the profiling mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Answer (score 2):

there is now (from 1.1.1 version) a 'skip' flag in pit.

So you can do things like :

```
<profile>
  <id>pit</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

in your module, and pit will skip

[INFO] --- pitest-maven:1.1.3:mutationCoverage (default-cli) @ module-selenium ---
[INFO] Skipping project