# Maven: How to skip sub-modules if a profile is activated?

Tags: maven, maven-module

I want Maven to skip building all sub-modules if the user neglects to specify a build profile. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305931/14731 explains how to include a module if a profile is selected, but not how to exclude it.

I understand I can copy the `<modules>` to build into all non-default profiles but the list of modules is huge and I have over 9 different profiles, making this a maintenance nightmare.

Is there a way to exclude/skip sub-modules if a profile is activated? Alternatively, is there a way to store the module list into a property and re-use it from multiple profiles without having to repeat the entire list each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1

> Is there a way to exclude/skip sub-modules if a profile is activated?

Only way I can see is to only define modules in profiles for which they should be active, perhaps including a 'special' profile that is `activeByDefault` if you want them active by default...

But that suffers from the issue that if somebody does

```
mvn verify -P+profile
```

Then the active by default profiles will still be active (i.e. the modules will still be there)

Note: `-Pprofile` activates the profile named `profile` and deactivates all active by default profiles. `-P-profile` deactivates the (presumably) active by default profile named `profile`. `-P+profile` activates the profile names `profile` without affecting the active profiles.

## Question 2

> Alternatively, is there a way to store the module list into a property and re-use it from multiple profiles without having to repeat the entire list each time?

Not that I am aware of. Property substitution is, in general, not available while Maven is computing the build plan.