# Working with multiple module using Maven for Automation

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, circular-dependency

I have a problem and i have confidence that you guys can clarify it.

I have created a java based automation project using maven project structure. I have applied the concept of Page Object Model in it. My project structure is like below.

```
Automation
Module1     
|_____  FrameworkCore.java  
|_____  FrameworkWebDriver.java 
|_____  DynamicMethodCalling.java   
|_____  RunSuit.csv 
Module2     
|_____CommonPage.java - extends Framework core  
|_____Pages 
|   |_____  LoginPage.java
|   |_____  HomePage.java
|   |_____  ContactPage.java
|_____Test  
    |_____  Test1.java
    |_____  Test2.java
```

--> I have created test functions in Test1 and Test2 and i am dynamically calling the methods based on the methodName.

-->In order to achieve the above i need to configure the Module1 as depenency in Module 2

> ("in-order to refer the webdriver defined in framework code")

AND Module 2 as dependency in Module1

> (in-order to call the methods from Test1 & Test2).

This causing the circular dependency.

Is there any way to avoid this circular dependency???

Note: i have searched a lot in the internet and have not found any suitable solution for this issue

Regards,
SomeshKumar Nagarajan

Comment: I suggest to you to take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16470159/3881320 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27072190/3881320

Comment: @DurdenP, I have already looked them but which is not possible in my project. Can you please tell me how to have that interface module for my project described above.?

Comment: Can you please provide the related pom.xml files and the error (build logs) shown by Maven? (you edit your question with it ;) )