# Maven release : Is there a way to prevent a module to be uploaded to Nexus?

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi modules Maven project : a parent and three child modules.

I want all of the modules to be built when I run `mvn clean package` on the parent. But I would also like one of those module *to not be uploaded to Nexus* when using `mvn deploy` (or `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`) on the parent. I want this module to be skipped, ignored. Only the parent and the two other modules would be uploaded to Nexus.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304110/skip-a-submodule-during-a-maven-build ?

Comment: Doesn't this particular module you don't want to be uploaded have modules upstream that depend on it?

Comment: @Makoto Not really. It's a module to build an installer (based on 7z's SFX) for one of the other module. But I want the generated .exe for this installer to be included in the other module group in Nexus (using a 'installer' classifier), not in its own group.

Comment: @vania-pooh Yeah, I guess it would be possible using profiles or that  `-pl` switch. Not my ideal solution but it should work. Thanks.

Comment: the maven deploy plugin has a skip property: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html - that may do what you want. The user property is "maven.deploy.skip".

Comment: @wemu The `skip` property works well. Add this comment as an answer if you want, and I'll accept it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven deploy plugin has a `skip` property: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

That should do what you want. The user property is "maven.deploy.skip".