# Maven multimodule project

Tags: maven

I am having parent pom.xml defining 3 child pom.xml files like A,B,C. all child modules were defined in parent module. when i run mvn install all the child modules will build. if I want to exclude B child module. how it is possible.

Comment: maybe a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539348/how-to-exclude-a-module-from-a-maven-reactor-build

Comment: not that question. here I want to exclude one pom.xml file to not build

Comment: Why would you like to exclude the child? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please see the second highest rated answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304110/skip-a-submodule-during-a-maven-build?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa